# (Android) Error when using SharedPreferences write/read in non-activity class

Tags: java, android, oop, sharedpreferences

Hello and thanks for reading.

I am trying to take an OOP approach to using SharedPreferences to save and retrieve data in the android app I am working on. I believe the following code is correct as it works in the java classes when used directly in a non-OOP manor. However, in this SharedPref class I made, I am getting an error in Eclipse at the MODE_PRIVATE and I can't figure out why. Thanks.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SharedPref {

    public static String File = "DPFile";

    public static void saveToSP(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences saveData = getSharedPreferences(File, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveData.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }


    public static String getSavedData(String key) {
         SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(File, MODE_PRIVATE);
         return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
}
```

Additionally, if I extend the Activity class getSharedPreferences becomes the line with the error and the following message:

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSharedPreferences(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to fix this is to pass a Context into your two methods, and have it look something like this:

```
public static void saveToSP(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences saveData = context.getSharedPreferences(File, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveData.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you elaborate on what context is? When saving data what should do I need to send as far as context? Would the getSavedData stay the same?

Comment: The documentation calls it the "Interface to global information about an application environment". Basically it's the entry point into stuff that the Android system manages. You'll need to modify getSavedData as well, but you should be able to do that pretty easily given my example :)

Comment: I think I can manage modifying the getSavedData method but an example  what you would pass as context would be really helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: The most common implementation of Context is Activity. If you're calling getSavedData from your Activity code, you can call it like this: String foo = SharedPref.getSavedData(this, "myKey"); "this" will be your Activity in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Context.MODE_PRIVATE. Its not an Activity, so you have to retrieve it from the Context.